# Javascript Object Function Scoping

Tags: javascript, scope

Let's say I have a class:

```
var asdf = new Class({
  myFunction: function () {
    //some stuff here
  },
  anotherFunction: function() {
    globalObject.dosomethingandusecallback( 
      function() { // this is the callback
        //how do I call myFunction() here? I can't seem to get it to work?
      }
    );
  }
});
```

I seem to have some scoping problems in trying to call myFunction within the definition of my callback function. What am I missing here? I thought it should have access to myFunction in this context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the `this` keyword into a variable outside of the callback function, and use that variable inside the callback:

```
anotherFunction: function() {
  var self = this;
  globalObject.dosomethingandusecallback( 
    function() { // this is the callback
      self.myFunction();
    }
  );
}
```